# check combo-box selected value string and change selexctedIndex in another combo box

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have combobox in which I am checking if the selected item text="Digital" then change the behavior in another combobox. It worked when I was checking by Selected Value but when i changed it to the following it stopping performing this behavior:

```
 if (cmbCamSupplier.SelectedItem.ToString().Equals("Digital"))
                cmbCamPrb.SelectedIndex = cmbCamSupplier.Items.IndexOf("Digital");
            //cmbCamPrb.SelectedIndex = 5;

            else
                //cmbCamPrb.SelectedIndex = cmbCamSupplier.Items.IndexOf("Digital");
                cmbCamPrb.SelectedIndex = 1;
```

What am I doing wrong. This should work but seems to be broken somewhere. Any help??

Before it was this:

```
if (cmbCamSupplier.SelectedValue.Equals(5))
                    cmbCamPrb.SelectedIndex = 5;
                else
                    cmbCamPrb.SelectedIndex = 1;
```

but with this I knew the Digital was located at ='5' but i wanted it by name not by the selected value

Comment: Any crashes or messages?

Comment: nothing just doesn't perform the required behavior

Comment: It depends what you're binding to the comboBox, if it's just strings that should work. If you're binding another object maybe not

Answer (score 2):

Text will give you the selected text of the editable portion, Selected Item will return you the object and selected index will return you the index. Does this work?

```
if (cmbCamSupplier.Text.Equals("Digital"))
        cmbCamPrb.SelectedIndex = cmbCamPrb.Items.IndexOf("Digital");
else
        cmbCamPrb.SelectedIndex = 1;
```

Comment: How about SelectedText Property as oppose to Text?

Comment: I agree. We need to see more code. We need to ensure that your ComboBox is configured properly.

Comment: and by more code do you mean more code of the function....? or the whole combobox....?

Comment: Try setting the SelectedValue as oppose to the SelectedIndex. What is the SelectedValue of Item "Digital"?

Comment: got it thanks :) my second line was wrong i didn't need the index of that rather the index to be 5.

Comment: @MasaRumi Silly error `cmbCamPrb.SelectedIndex = cmbCamSupplier.Items.IndexOf("Digital");` change to: `cmbCamPrb.SelectedIndex = cmbCamPrb.Items.IndexOf("Digital");` LOL guess we figured it out at the same time.